# Why doesn't SymPy really calculate such an integral?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I'm trying to run the following sample in sympy

```
from sympy.functions import *
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_latex=False, use_unicode=False)
shift = Symbol('shift', real=True, nonzero=True)
x = Symbol('x', real=True, nonzero=True)
p = Symbol('p', real=True, nonzero=True)

integrate(exp(-p)/(p+shift), (p, x, oo))
```

For some reason, it does not actually solve this integral. It just prints out the original integral.

```
 oo             
  /             
 |              
 |      -p      
 |     e        
 |  --------- dp
 |  p + shift   
 |              
/               
x
```

But if I replace shift with some numeric constant then it does calculate integral:

```
integrate(exp(-p)/(p+0.1), (p, x, oo))
```

```
                    /           I*pi\
-1.10517091807565*Ei\(x + 0.1)*e    /
```

So it is possible to calculate this integral assuming shift is a real number.

The question is: it is possible to force sympy calculate this integral using shift as variable of type Symbol?

Comment: if you define `x` and `shift` as positive it can do the integral.

Comment: It works. Thanks.